# Windows batch command response an input request

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, runas

I am writing a simple batch automation script. I will use runas command to run cmd.exe under another user account. The system asks me to input password. How to response the input request from script. 
The command is something like this.

```
runas /noprofile /user:testuser1 cmd.exe
```

The output is shown below. 
[image]

Comment: & To answer your question, check option of running it via vbscript. Also, there is a freeware called `sanur` (`runas` spelled backwards) for this purpose.

Comment: If you can actually get cygwin components, particularly [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) command from `tcl/tk`, that can be used too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below line to auto enter the password while using runas, you will have to use a switch /savecred.  You'll have to enter the password on the script's first run, but it will be saved after that.

`runas /noprofile /user:joe@example.com /savecred script.bat`

or

`runas /noprofile /user:joe-pc\joe /savecred script.bat`

If you want to delete saved password, then you will have to search for  ***Credential Manager*** in Control Panel.